# Unable to log remote console arguments Output omitted for a large object that exceeds the limits

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can not get object when develop extension of vscode, it give me this "Unable to log remote console arguments Output omitted for a large object that exceeds the limits"

how can I can the object print on debug console?

[image]

Comment: chop it up in smaller pieces, split the text on newlines or the first space after 400 characters.....

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue these days.
But in my case, I use a callback to fix the issue.

Before:

```
getDataFromServer = async (param1, param2) => {
  const data = "param1" + "param2";
  return data;
}

const data:any = await getDataFromServer(param1, param2);
console.log(data);
```

After:

```
const callBack = (data) => {
 console.log(data);
};
await getDataFromServer(param1, param2, callBack);

getDataFromServer = async (param1, param2, callBack) => {
  const data = "param1" + "param2";
  return callBack(data);
}
```